# why this regexp return such array

Tags: javascript, regex

I met this example on MDN for string's match method:

```
var str = "For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1";
var re = /(chapter \d+(\.\d)*)/i;
var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found);

// logs ["Chapter 3.4.5.1", "Chapter 3.4.5.1", ".1"]

// "Chapter 3.4.5.1" is the first match and the first value 
//  remembered from (Chapter \d+(\.\d)*).

// ".1" is the last value remembered from (\.\d)
```

I am not very clear about the matching on RegExp on JS, it seems should return ["Chapter 3.4.5.1", ".4.5.1"], can anybody explain why the result is like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ["Chapter 3.4.5.1", "Chapter 3.4.5.1", ".1"]
      |                        |             |
      |                        |             |
Matched string           Characters inside Characters inside the group index 2. Basically `*` would do a greedy match. In this  (\.\d)* , it eats up all the `.\d` and captures only the last `.\d` part because you fail to capture the following `*` .
                          the group index
                              1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lY1zP4/1)

To get the desired output, you need to capture the following `*` in this `(\.\d)*` pattern and also you need to remove the first capturing group.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lY1zP4/2)

```
> var str = "For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1";
undefined
> var re = /chapter \d+((?:\.\d)*)/i;
undefined
> str.match(re);
[ 'Chapter 3.4.5.1',
  '.4.5.1',
  index: 26,
  input: 'For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1' ]
```

Comment: understand what you said, but I could hardly find documentation on matching and capturing behaviour of (\.\d)*, if you have, giving it here, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: see the explanation at the right side in this link http://regex101.com/r/vW4vV5/1

Comment: I tested if "Chapter 3.4.5.1"

Answer (score 1):

`str.match()` returns an array of `[whole regexp match, paren1match, paren2match ...]`

To acheive ["Chapter 3.4.5.1", ".4.5.1"] your code should look like:

```
var str = "For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1";
var re = /chapter \d+([\.\d]*)/i;
var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found);
```

Comment: understand what you said, but I could hardly find documentation on matching and capturing behaviour of (\.\d)*, if you have, giving it here, I would greatly appreciate

Comment: (\.\d)* will match a sequence of dots followed by a digit (.9.9.5.6.2 will match, but 5.5.5 and .5..5 will not). ([\.\d]*) this will match a sequence of digits and dots in any order (99.4.....56.3..15. will match)