# Why does this loop through Regex groups print the output twice?

Tags: c#, regex

I have written this very straight forward regex code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RegexTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = "\"foobar123==\"";
            Regex r = new Regex("^\"(.*)\"$");
            Match m = r.Match(a);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(g.Index);
                    Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the output is

```
0
"foobar123=="
1
foobar123==
```

I don't understand why does it print twice. why should there be a capture at index 0? when I say in my regex `^\"` and I am not using capture for this.

Sorry if this is very basic but I don't write Regex on a daily basis.

According to me, this code should print only once and the index should be 1 and the value should be foobar==

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000752/why-this-regexp-return-such-array

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happens because group zero is special: it returns the entire match.

From the [Regex documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis added):

> A simple regular expression pattern illustrates how numbered (unnamed) and named groups can be referenced either programmatically or by using regular expression language syntax. The regular expression `((?<One>abc)\d+)?(?<Two>xyz)(.*)` produces the following capturing groups by number and by name. **The first capturing group (number 0) always refers to the entire pattern.**

```
#      Name              Group
- ---------------- --------------------------------
0 0 (default name) ((?<One>abc)\d+)?(?<Two>xyz)(.*)

1 1 (default name) ((?<One>abc)\d+)

2 2 (default name) (.*)

3 One (?<One>abc)

4 Two (?<Two>xyz)
```

If you do not want to see it, start the output from the first group.

Answer (score 13):

A regex captures several groups at once. Group `0` is the entire matched region (including the accents). Group `1` is the group defined by the brackets.

Say your regex has the following form:

```
A(B(C)D)E.
```

With `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` end `E` regex expressions.

Then the following groups will be matched:

```
0 A(B(C)D)E
1 B(C)D
2 C
```

The `i`-th group starts at the `i`-th open bracket. And you can say the "zero-th" open bracket is implicitly placed at the begin of the regex (and ends at the end of the regex).

If you want to omit group `0`, you can use the `Skip` method of the *LINQ* framework:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RegexTest1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string a = "\"foobar123==\"";
            Regex r = new Regex("^\"(.*)\"$");
            Match m = r.Match(a);
            if (m.Success) {
                foreach (Group g in m.Groups.Skip(1)) {//Skipping the first (thus group 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(g.Index);
                    Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably not the whole story with Dot-Net capture group counting. As named groups are added the default is count them and count them last. These can optionally be changed. The counting default for something like `A(?<B>B(C)D)E` is not what you'd expect.

Comment: @sln: True, this was of course a brief introduction (how unnamed groups are numbered). If a user wants more info, one should always consult the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
0
"foobar123=="  --  Matched string.
```

Entire match by a pattern  would be found at index 0.

```
1
foobar123==     -- Captured string.
```

group index 1 contains the characters which are captured by the first [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Perhaps some explanation is appropriate?

Comment: I did not downvote (did +1). But by simply demonstrating output, most people don't get the point...

Answer (score 5):

Using @dasblinkenlight regex as an example...

This is not the whole story with Dot-Net capture group counting.
As named groups are added, the default is count them and count them last.
These can optionally be changed.

Of course group 0 always contain the entire match. Group counting really starts at 1
because you can't specify a back reference (in the regex) to group 0, it conflicts
with the *binary* construct `\0000`.

Here is counting with named/normal groups in the Dot-Net the default state.

```
 (                                  # (1 start)
      (?<One> abc )                 #_(3)         
      \d+ 
 )?                                 # (1 end)
 (?<Two> xyz )                      #_(4)         
 ( .* )                             # (2)
```

Here it is with names last turned *OFF*.

```
 (                                  # (1 start)
      (?<One> abc )                 # (2)
      \d+ 
 )?                                 # (1 end)
 (?<Two> xyz )                      # (3)
 ( .* )                             # (4)
```

Here it is with named counting turned *OFF*.

```
 (                                  # (1 start)
      (?<One> abc )
      \d+ 
 )?                                 # (1 end)
 (?<Two> xyz )
 ( .* )                             # (2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return only one by removing the group 1  using `?:`

```
 Regex r = new Regex("^\"(?:.*)\"$");
```

**[Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v0ZWkR)**

Every time you use `()` you are creating groups and you can reference them later using back references $1,$2,$3 of course in the case of your expression simpler will be:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^\".*\"$");
```

Which is not using parenthesis at all

Comment: But then the brackets are not used to "capture" content. You only return group `0`: the matching string. Many applications use brackets to capture special parts.